# div height depend on content div with pseudo code

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi how do i force wpdemos_wrapper div to be basing his height to the content? If i remove the height 900px the 2nd background wont appear.

```
div.wpdemos_wrapper 
{   
    position: relative;     
    min-height:100%;    
    padding:0 0 20px;   
    background-image: url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_top.png");    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: top center;    
    background-size: contain;   
    width: 100%;    
    z-index: 0;     
    height: 900px; 
} 
div.wpdemos_wrapper:before 
{   
    position: absolute;     
    content: "";    
    background-image: url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_bottom.png");     
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    background-position: bottom center;     
    background-size: contain;   
    width: 100%;    
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;    
    height: 100%;   
    z-index: -1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to apply the `bg_honeycomb_top.png` image to the `:before` pseudo-element and then apply the `bg_honeycomb_bottom.png` image to the main `div.wpdemos_wrapper`. The `:before` pseudo-element appears before the content in the div, so it is much easier that way.  :) You can then remove the fixed height on the main div and clean it up a bit.

### Sample code

This will allow you to repeat the background images across the entire width of the top and bottom of the `div`. This is using `repeat-x` for the images but you can change it to `contain` if you're wanting.  :)

```
div.wpdemos_wrapper {
    padding:0 0 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_bottom.png") repeat-x bottom center;
}
div.wpdemos_wrapper:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_top.png") repeat-x top center;
    height: 20px; /* height of the background image */
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Adding `display: block;` is just helping the `height` apply to the `:before` pseudo-element properly.

Answer (score 0):

this is my new code nerwood. It is now working fine with height issues. However the top background wont appear..

```
    div.wpdemos_wrapper {
        position: relative; 
        padding:0 0 20px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_bottom.png") no-repeat bottom center/contain;
        width: 100%;
    }
    div.wpdemos_wrapper:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("./images/body/bg_honeycomb_top.png") no-repeat top center/contain;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: I'll add a code sample to my answer as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use `display: table` on `div.wpdemos_wrapper` and corresponding `display: table-cell` on its children? Then the wrapper will always be the same height as their children even without an explicit height.